# bad operand type for unary -: 'str' error in geographiclib

Tags: python, pandas, geographic-lib

I need to find out the Longitude and Latitude distance using geographiclib

It is giving this type error:

> Error: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

```
Geo = Geodesic.WGS84
for i in range(0, 2112):
    Lat1=df3['Lat'].iloc[i]
    Long1=df3['Long'].iloc[i]
    Lat2=df3['Lat'].iloc[i+1]
    Long2=df3['Long'].iloc[i+1]
    df3['dis'] = Geo.Inverse( Lat1, Long1, Lat2, Long2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Geo library probably trying to negate a string? convert to float first. check the type of your lat/long variables

Comment: lat/long values in my data is positive in csv file.

Comment: Yes, but when you read them from the csv file they will be strings, not numbers. You have to explicitly convert them (using `float` or similar) either (preferably) when reading them the first time, or just before sending them to `Geo.Inverse()`.

Comment: Are you trying to compute pairwise distances? Or, are you trying to compute consecutive distances?

Comment: I am find pairwise distance sir.